# Latest docker (containerd) updates break everything and all container stopped

Tags: linux, docker, containerd

All my docker instances are not working anymore because the following error message appears right after the latest containerd updates:

```
Feb  4 14:16:19 ngs-he-site-03 dockerd[830]: time="2023-02-04T14:16:19.524452673Z" level=error msg="failed to start container" container=6f8e87238300e1082f1e8e86d03233ed31018ac3d6d0d205bcd7fd4ffb847539 error="AppArmor enabled on system but the docker-default profile could not be loaded: running apparmor_parser apparmor_parser --version failed with output: \nerror: exec: "apparmor_parser": executable file not found in $PATH"
```

anyone else who sees the same error?

you can fix the problem by

```
apt install apparmor apparmor-utils
```

but before, everything stops working...

why nobody test those updates before releasing them to the world?

and the problem appears on every host, who has the containerd service running.

Comment: Same here. All Docker Containers were stopped this morning after automatic package updates. Your solution works.

Answer (score 3):

Man you saved many hours of my life! Thank you!

```
apt install apparmor apparmor-utils
```

This is fix all!